# API searchtweets-v2, unable to import gen_request_parameters

Tags: import, twitter-api-v2

I'm using the version 2 searchtweets api for learning proposes.

Following the documentation available here: https://pypi.org/project/searchtweets-v2/, I'm trying to run the following code:

```
    import json
        from datetime import date
        import os
        
        from searchtweets import gen_request_parameters, load_credentials, collect_results

def query_data_from_twitter():
   query = gen_request_parameters("#Messi", None, results_per_call=100)
   print("We are getting data from Twitter ...", query)
   search_args = load_credentials("~/.twitter_keys.yaml", yaml_key="search_tweets_v2", env_overwrite=False)
   return collect_results(query, max_tweets=100, result_stream_args=search_args)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'gen_request_parameters' from 'searchtweets'
```

What I've tried so far: uninstalling the previous version of the library and using "from searchtweets.utils import gen_request_parameters.
Do you have any suggestions to use this solve this importing issue?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by using the code "source activate" in my venv, and reinstalling the library after:

```
cd airflow_venv
source bin/activate
pip3 install searchtweets-v2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
pip install searchtweets-v2

Comment: Hey, It's already installed, so I just get the message "Requirement already satisfied"